# D3: Hierarchy child accessor function using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, rest, d3.js

I'm looking to represent a full hierarchy of items, which are accessible via a RESTful API.

To do this, I would like to utilize D3's tree layout to load and draw nodes. This API can return all elements of a given type. The children of those elements, however, are accessed via a reference URL, rather than a nested array.

In setting up my tree in D3, I am attempting to set a child accessor function that uses d3.json() to return all children for a given node using this URL. Here is my tree builder function thus far, where `root` is a top-level item with a `Children` attribute:

```
function buildTreeFor(root) {
    var tree = d3.layout.tree();
    tree.children(function(node) {
        d3.json(node.Children._ref, function(data) {
            return data;
        });
    });
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
    var links = tree.links(nodes);
}
```

As one would expect, these links are empty, and the nodes do not reference the discovered children. After reading the D3 documentation and some tutorials, I'm at a loss for a pattern here. I could return the child data in a Promise, but where would it be resolved? Somewhere in the node resolution process behind the scenes?

I need to ensure that all levels of this hierarchy are represented in the final diagram. What can I do to wait for the resolution of these AJAX calls?

Thanks!